# Can i use postMessage on an iframe, who's html is passed via - srcdoc attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am unable to call postMessage in case, I pass html in the srcdoc attribute

**without** `sandbox = "allow-scripts"`
, it give following error

`Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://example.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://example.com:444').`

---

**with** `sandbox = "allow-scripts"`
, it give following error

`Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://example.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').`

---

I would like to call postMessage without the sandbox attribute, can I?

if not, is there any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can.

The problem your error messages are complaining about is that you did set the `target-origin` parameter of `Window.postMessage( message, target-origin, transferable )` to an invalid value.
You didn't show your code, but if I had to make a guess, I'd say you didn't set it at all and thus it did default to your current page's origin.

Since your target frame doesn't have an `src` but an `srcdoc` attribute, its location will be `about:srcdoc` and its origin will be `null`, so any other value than `"*"` for postMessage's `target-origin` will make the request fail.
**You must set it to `"*"`.**

```js
frame.onload = (e) => {
  frame.contentWindow.postMessage( 'hello frame', '*' );
};
```

```html
<iframe id="frame" srcdoc="
  <html>
  <body>
  <pre id='log'></pre>
  <script>
    const log = document.getElementById( 'log' );
    onmessage = (e) => log.textContent = e.data;
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
"></iframe>
```